# Should I always keep calm no matter how others violate me?

Tags: friends

I am 21 years old and a college student. I found I became accustomed to being calm all the time, and, seldom be angry(at least from appearance).

Is it beneficial for an interpersonal relationship?

Comment: Questions asking "What should I do?" have been determined to be off topic on this site. Determining what to do is much more of a personal decision than an interpersonal skill.

Comment: @Raditz_35 you mean save **time**? or something? (apology for my poor English)

Comment: I think you should give some specific situations, where you felt this behaviour might have been problematic, the results of those and how you would have liked it to go instead. Did people just go over you? Did they not notice that you didn't enjoy something? Do people mistake your behaviour for carelessness, boredom or indifference?

Comment: Something led to you asking that question I assume? If you don't have a specific problem and this is just philosophy, you will have a hard time getting people to reopen it.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your suggestions :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: Yes, it's beneficial.

Slightly more nuanced answer: Yes, most of the time with a couple of exceptions.

It's great as long as you can express your true feelings as well. If the only way to remain calm is to ignore every comment and bottle up any negative emotion it will at some point go wrong. You'll either no longer be able to cope with the emotions you don't want to express (out of fear you'll nog longer remain calm) or the people around you could see you as indifferent/emotionless about everything.

As long as you are able to express your anger/sadness/... in a calm way you're way better off than someone who can't remain calm that easily.
Otherwise it's fine to shout every once in a while when someone really got on your nerves about something, as long as you calm down afterwards and explain why they should not do/say what they did.